# dynamically generated invalid html

Tags: javascript, html

I know that invalid html can cause some seo-issues. But that only applies on the html-source right?

what about html that is served validly to the client, but then via some fancy js it gets manipulated into a new structure with markup violations?

Example. I have an unordered list with several li-elements, but want them separated in clusters to be displayed on a row. So once the user performs a certain action the `ul` includes several divs (`class="liCluster"`) that contains the original list.

I know it's not a really swanky way to do it, but is there actually some serious problem with that, that I might not see yet?
At least it looks fine so far from a client's point of view...

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine because most browsers are smart enough to know what you're trying to do. However, This takes the browser more time do do.

Most search engines are also smart enough to know what you're trying to do. Although search engines don't care much for markup, rather they care about content and how that content relates to different parts of your website. A poorly formatted ul of lis is not likely to make a massive impact in SEO.

That being said, why would you put DIVs in a ul if they're not wrapped in lis? Most browsers will remove the offending markup and you're going to make more trouble for yourself, Just learn how to use CSS and realise that you can then do everything you need to do and you can do it the correct way.